# android screen size not scaling

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I'm trying to support multiple screen sizes but I'm obviously missing something
I'm testing between a Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro  (10.1 Tablet)  and Samsung Note 3  (phone/fab)

```
DisplayMetrics      WidthPixels HeightPixels    Density      DensityDPI  
Tab  Pro  reports      2560        1600           2.0           320 
Note 3    reports      1920        1080           3.0           480
```

I have all the layouts in  /res/layouts and They all start with
RelativeLayout   match_parent for layout_width and layout_height

My AndroidManifest.xml   has

Ideally I would like to support screen resolutions of  1024 x 768  and larger
Which both the Note 3 (at 1920x1080)  and Tab Pro (at 2560x1600)  are

On the Tab Pro  everything lays out the way I would like
On the Note 3 you are only seeing the  upper left corner of the screen
It is almost as if the Tablet Layout has been cut in quarters

```
    Y X
    X X
```

And the Note 3 shows the Y only    while the Tab Pro shows it all

Please help ? ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can scale ur images, backgrounds, in other words the elements used in xml to be able to run ur app in different screen sizes. for this see this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: and bear in mind: you have to use different images for different resolutions.